# How can I provide overridable configuration per endpoint in an AspNetCore web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net Core api middleware for which I want to expose some configuration options via appsettings.json:

```cs
public class MyMiddleware: IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // something like this, except get data from appsettings.json instead of attributes
        var attribute = context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<MyAttribute>();
        if (attribute is not null) {
            // do the things
        }
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

The attribute pattern that I have has advantages that I would like to keep in that I can place the attribute on the action method, the class containing it or a base class and the middleware utilizes the most specific one. Unfortunately the attributes can only be modified by rebuilding the application and deploying a new version.

Is there a built-in way or otherwise reasonable way to map an options data store to endpoints?

I was thinking something in appsettings.json like this with globbing rules for path traversal similarities:

```json
{
   "ConfigurationRules": [
        {
            "Match": "/foo/**/bar",
            "Option1": "..."
        },
        {
            "Match": "/foo",
            "Option1": "..."
        },
        {
            "Match": "/**",
            "Option1": "..."
        },
   ]     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://medium.com/@vijaynathv/accessing-custom-configuration-section-in-net-core-6dc9fa72ed24) explains how to map a custom configuration section to an object that you can use in code.  Your middleware would have to accept an `IConfiguration` object so that the caller can pass it into your setup method inside of `ConfigureServices`.  Something like this:

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

//...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyMiddleware(Configuration);
}
```

Then in your `AddMyMiddleware` extension method, you can get your configuration section like this:

```cs
var rules = Configuration.GetSection("ConfigurationRules");
services.Configure<MyConfigurationRulesClass>(rules);
```

Now this instance of `MyConfigurationRulesClass` will be available through dependency injection wherever you need it - e.g. by adding `IOptions<MyConfigurationRulesClass> myConfiguration` to the constructor

Comment: Yes this much is clear to me, I was trying to find a matching engine or some similar mechanism such that my middleware can call a method and get the configuration that most specifically applies to the current request.

Comment: Does this answer your needs?  https://blog.markvincze.com/matching-route-templates-manually-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Maybe it helps; I just found this also: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39081#issuecomment-996507523

It seems somewhere I can mutate endpoint metadata such that my middleware will simply get the correct values as if it was an attribute. If I can do that in my registration somehow I would be good to go.

Comment: I think I have 2 potential solutions: 1. add metadata in app.UseEndpoints in startup after MapControllers() and 2. register a service in startup that uses route matching to match a passed string to a configuration block... I am leaning to the second.

Thank you for the direction.